# how i display price bar slide in view

Tags: views, search, commerce

i am a amateur in DRUPAL, i want CREATE a commercial page,
i want display something like this in the PICTURE, what module i used ? AND WHAT is steps?
because i can't FOUND any thing about this:

[image]

I want some thing simply and efficace
Please someone can help me !????
tgojrtorjbojrojgbjogbjobgfjob

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about "Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided". Please see the [help] for more information about what's on-topic here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Views Contextual Range Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter) module.

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) that adds the option to [contextually filter](http://drupal.org/node/1578558) not just by a single value, but also by range.

Image from module page.

[image]

Comment: @zaferro Clive is a moderator here (as am I) and am responsible for keeping questions, answers, and comments within scope and goals of the site (see the [tour] and [help]).  I am going to clean up a few comments, and delete this one after a little while.